# Magento2 Limiter on product review page not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am using Magento 2.1.4, Limiter for the product review on product details page not working. After changing limiter value ajax is not working. Please refer screenshot
[image]

If I change page limiter then I want one ajax call which is not working

Comment: What's the page you're talking about?

Comment: Could you provide more detail?

Comment: I have Edited my que please check